# Import CSV file into Django model

Tags: django-models, django-database

I want to import a CSV file into my Django database, but my CSV file only contains part of the model. in the CSV file the data for the objects are: title, release_date, artist and Spotify url. but the rest I want to leave blank (because these need to be put in manually) how to?

model:

```
class Album(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
description = models.TextField(blank=True)
release_date = models.CharField(max_length=10)
artist = models.CharField(max_length=100)
genre = models.CharField(choices=GENRE_CHOICES, max_length=20)
image = models.ImageField(default='default2.jpg', upload_to='album_pics')
spotify_url = models.URLField(max_length=250)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

Comment: I would advise to use `django-importexport`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem could you perhaps explain it a bit more, or link a tutorial? I can only find tutorials and documentation for the export part

Comment: https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/,